# How to fix Oracle SQL Developer - vendor code 17002?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I install only Oracle SQL Developer from their page. When i try to create new conntection(user) program show me error like:

> An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
>
> IO: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
>
> Vendor code 17002

I try find file  tnsnames.ora and  listener.ora they not exist. This is my first use Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: This really isn't an sql question. How to install or connect to oracle is covered in many places.  You might provide more detail about your installation. Did you actually install oracle?  Where?  Is oracle (and the listener) running?  See the following, as one starting point: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536628400346015170

Comment: You can't install just SQL Developer. It's the tool for working with Oracle databases. You have to have an Oracle database instance installed before you can use SQL Developer.

Comment: @KenWhite in that case i will install Oracle Database Software or something different?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is for working with Oracle databases, as I said before. It doesn't work with anything but Oracle databases, so yes - you have to install Oracle database softwware.

Comment: SQL Dev is a client tool for working with _oracle_ databases.  Why would you install  "something else"?  Sounds like this is just a personal learning platform, so I'd suggest you install Oracle XE.

Comment: Besides all the comments said here regarding you obviously need a database to connect to, there is a wrong assumption in saying that you can **only** connect to Oracle. SQL Developer can connect to Postgres and MySQL with specific plugins of jdbc. You have a lot of examples in the web on how do it. https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-connect-postgresql-using-sql-developer-visual-studio-and-dbeaver

Comment: Yes you can "just install SQL Developer" and you can run it too. However you will need a database server if you want to do anything meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

Vendor code 17002 usually comes when **Listener Control is down.**

lsnrctl (Listener Control) is an SQL*Net utility used for controlling database listeners. A listener is required for allowing remote (not local) clients to connect to the Oracle database via the network.

You can validate it by using below command

```
lsnrctl status
```

If its down you can use the below command to start it.

```
lsnrctl start
```

now check the status and try to connect the db. it will work ;)

Comment: My attempt to start came back with 
TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
And above that, it gave me the file that needed adjustment, i.e.
System parameter file is D:\(snip)\network\admin\listener.ora
That listener.ora file had the prior/wrong ip number after relaunching my AWS EC2 instance.  After fixing that ip number, I could start the listener service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lsnrctl status` command to verify that the listener is down, and `lsnrctl start` to start your listener.

Check this link for more details:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_developer_vendor_error_17002.htm

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need a database to connect to.  If you're just getting started, then Express Edition is the ideal option. Here's a complete video walkthrough of download and installing it done by the Oracle on Windows team

https://youtu.be/DYleroLay5E

Take note of the host/port/service strings mentioned in the video. Then with SQL Developer, you will use those to connect