# Oracle19c Network Adapter Stops Working Every Reboot

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I installed Oracle 19c in my laptop. After installation, I tried connecting to a DB (localhost) in SQL Developer and I was able to connect to it successfully. However when I reboot my laptop, I now keep on getting this issue. Issue also happens if I shut down.

[image]

My workaround is to clean install Oracle 19c every time it happens.
Can someone knowledgeable share what could be the possible cause of this?

Comment: [This error message usually means that the Listener service isn't running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69595734/how-to-fix-oracle-sql-developer-vendor-code-17002). Check your Windows services, and try starting the Oracle services. They might not be set to automatically start when your computer starts. They might also be printing errors to the Windows logs.